# Splice not working with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I now try to make Items list form that are able to **add**, **edit** and **delete**.
Add and edit are work fine, however, when I trying to delete it is not working as expected.

Here, is my partial of my code, that consist of delete button.

```
      <!-- Added Items Stage -->
      <div ng-repeat-start="item in items" ng-form="editItemForm" class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" name="description" ng-model="item.description" placeholder="description" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="number" name="quantity" pattern="\d*" ng-model="item.quantity" placeholder="quantity" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" name="price" ng-model="item.price" placeholder="price" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <select name="taxType" ng-model="item.taxType" required>
            <option value="ZR">ZR</option>
            <option value="SR">SR</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-20" ng-bind="(item.quantity&&item.price)?((item.quantity*item.price) | currency:''):'0.00'"></div>
        <div class="col col-10">
          <button type="button" class="button button-assertive button-clear icon ion-close-circled" ng-click="deleteItem(item)"></button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr ng-repeat-end>
```

Second part is how I delete item

```
$scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
    $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
};
```

I tried pass in `$index`, or use `delete` instead of splice, but it still cannot work. Help me please. Thank you.

This is my [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/A07ApOR2GtH9WJj4Keiq?p=preview)

Note: I think the item removed, but the html not updated.

Comment: The problem is, the `item` is an object and `$scope.items` is array of objects. "Array.indexOf" does not work. When you say it seems it not just updating in UI but splice is happening, when undefined index is passed to splice the first element will be removed. So it is not expected behaviour.

Comment: @Exception, nope, you wrong

Comment: @Exception then why is the proper index being found? You can indeed use `indexOf()` if the object is a reference to object in array

Comment: @charlietfl Check this in your console `[{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:34}].indexOf({b:2})` it says `-1`. Default indexOf does not support it, but I think angular is adding custom indexOf function. And do this it will give you exact index `[1,2,3,4,6,6].indexOf(4)`

Comment: @Grundy Which part is wrong.

Comment: @Exception those are 2 different object references. Pay close attention to what I wrote

Comment: @Exception that's because the object literal in `indexOf` is not the same object at index 1. Try `var b = {b:2}; [{a:1}, b, {c:34}].indexOf(b)`

Comment: @Edward  I think you have some unusual things going on with `isolate-form` and removing controller all mixed into `ng-start-repeat/end-repeat`

Comment: @Phil Yes that case, you are correct.

Comment: @Exception and that is the case in OP's code

Answer (score 2):

That sometimes happens when Angular is not aware that a change has been made to the model. When that's the case you can force an update by wrapping your function inside a `$timeout` with no delay:

```
$scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
    });
};
```

Don't forget to inject the `$timeout` service into the controller.

Comment: This is not the case here

Comment: Worked in my case +1 vote from me...thanks a lot @R. Kazeno

Answer (score 1):

I not quite understand **why?** but your problem in *ng-form* attribute on your repeater.

If you remove it - all work

```js
var nameApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngMessages']);

nameApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('auth', {
      url: '/auth',
      templateUrl: 'auth.html',
    })
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/auth");

});


nameApp.directive('isolateForm', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?form',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      if (!ctrl) {
        return;
      }

      // Do a copy of the controller
      var ctrlCopy = {};
      angular.copy(ctrl, ctrlCopy);

      // Get the parent of the form
      var parent = elm.parent().controller('form');
      // Remove parent link to the controller
      parent.$removeControl(ctrl);

      // Replace form controller with a "isolated form"
      var isolatedFormCtrl = {
        $setValidity: function(validationToken, isValid, control) {
          ctrlCopy.$setValidity(validationToken, isValid, control);
          parent.$setValidity(validationToken, true, ctrl);
        },
        $setDirty: function() {
          elm.removeClass('ng-pristine').addClass('ng-dirty');
          ctrl.$dirty = true;
          ctrl.$pristine = false;
        },
      };
      angular.extend(ctrl, isolatedFormCtrl);
    }
  };
}]);



nameApp.controller('AuthCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

  $scope.newItem = {
    description: undefined,
    quantity: undefined,
    price: undefined,
    taxType: undefined
  };

  $scope.items = [];

  $scope.addItem = function() {
    console.log({
      description: $scope.newItem.description,
      quantity: $scope.newItem.quantity,
      price: $scope.newItem.price,
      taxType: $scope.newItem.taxType
    });

    $scope.items.push({
      description: $scope.newItem.description,
      quantity: $scope.newItem.quantity,
      price: $scope.newItem.price,
      taxType: $scope.newItem.taxType
    });

    console.log($scope.items);

    $scope.newItem.description = undefined;
    $scope.newItem.quantity = undefined;
    $scope.newItem.price = undefined;
    $scope.newItem.taxType = "SR";

  };

  $scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
    $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
  };

  $scope.authorization = {
    referenceNo: '',
  };

  $scope.signIn = function(form) {
    if (form.$valid) {
      $state.go('home');
    }
  };

});

nameApp.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```css
.error-container {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.error-container:last-child {
    margin: 5px 0 0;
}

.error {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.error i {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #B83E2C;  
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.last-error-container > .error {
  padding: 10px 16px 0;
}

.has-errors {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #B83E2C;
}

.no-errors {
  border-bottom: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="starter">
 
  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-messages.js"></script>  
  
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
      <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>
  
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  
  <script id="auth.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Authorization Page">  
    
      <ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="AuthCtrl">
      
        <h2 style="text-align: center;">Form validation example</h2><br/>
        
        <form name="newDocumentForm" ng-submit="signIn(newDocumentForm)" novalidate>
        
          <div class="list">
          
            <label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-errors' : newDocumentForm.referenceNo.$invalid && newDocumentForm.$submitted, 'no-errors' : newDocumentForm.referenceNo.$valid  && newDocumentForm.$submitted}">
              <span class="input-label">Reference No</span>
              <input type="text" name="referenceNo" ng-model="authorization.username" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" required>
            </label>
            
            <div class="error-container" ng-show="newDocumentForm.referenceNo.$error && newDocumentForm.$submitted" ng-messages="newDocumentForm.referenceNo.$error">
              <div ng-messages-include="error-list.html"></div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
        
          <!-- Title -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">Description</div>
            <div class="col">Quantity</div>
            <div class="col">Price</div>
            <div class="col">Tax Type</div>
            <div class="col col-20">Amount</div>
            <div class="col col-10"></div>
          </div>
     
          <!-- Added Items Stage -->
          <div ng-repeat-start="item in items" class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" name="description" ng-model="item.description" placeholder="description" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="number" name="quantity" pattern="\d*" ng-model="item.quantity" placeholder="quantity" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" name="price" ng-model="item.price" placeholder="price" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <select name="taxType" ng-model="item.taxType" required>
                <option value="ZR">ZR</option>
                <option value="SR">SR</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-20" ng-bind="(item.quantity&&item.price)?((item.quantity*item.price) | currency:''):'0.00'"></div>
            <div class="col col-10">
              <button type="button" class="button button-assertive button-clear icon ion-close-circled" ng-click="deleteItem(item)"></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <hr ng-repeat-end>
          
     <!-- Adding Stage -->
          <div ng-form="addItemForm" class="row" isolate-form>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" name="description" ng-model="newItem.description" placeholder="description" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="number" pattern="\d*" name="quantity" ng-model="newItem.quantity" placeholder="quantity" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <!--<input type="text" name="price" ng-model="newItem.price" placeholder="price" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/" required/>-->
              <input type="text" name="price" ng-model="newItem.price" placeholder="price" step="0.01" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <select name="taxType" ng-model="newItem.taxType" required>
                <option value="ZR">ZR</option>
                <option value="SR">SR</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-20" ng-bind="(newItem.quantity&&newItem.price)?((newItem.quantity*newItem.price) | currency:''):'0.00'"></div>
            <div class="col col-10">
              <button type="button" ng-disabled="addItemForm.$invalid" class="button button-balanced button-clear icon ion-plus-circled" ng-click="addItem()"></button>
            </div>
          </div>
            
          <div class="error-container last-error-container" ng-show="addItemForm.price.$error.pattern" ng-messages="addItemForm.price.$error">
            <div ng-messages-include="currency-error-list.html"></div>
          </div>
          
          <button class="button button-full button-positive" type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
            
        </form>   
        
      </ion-content>
      
    </ion-view>
  </script>  
  
  <script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Second page">
      <ion-content class="padding">
          <h1>Wellcome</h1>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>   

  <script id="currency-error-list.html" type="text/ng-template">  
    <div class="error" ng-message="pattern">
      <i class="ion-information-circled"></i> 
      Invalid currency format!
    </div>
  </script> 

  <script id="error-list.html" type="text/ng-template">  
    <div class="error" ng-message="required">
      <i class="ion-information-circled"></i> 
      This field is required!
    </div>
    <div class="error" ng-message="minlength">
      <i class="ion-information-circled"></i> 
      Minimum length of this field is 5 characters!
    </div>
    <div class="error" ng-message="maxlength">
      <i class="ion-information-circled"></i> 
      Maximum length of this field is 20 characters!
    </div>
  </script>
```

Comment: Probably easier to just link to the modified Plunker ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/gAk1wONFKFosoEwGOQzn?p=preview

Comment: @Phil, in a snippet, simply, immediately evident that the all ok :-) possibly somthing internal `ng-form` prevent update view, can you explain something about this?

Comment: I just find the SO snippets make for messy answers due to all the extra bits (CSS, 3rd party libs, etc). I think the problem is most probably due to a scope conflict. `ngRepeat`'s scoping is complex; it's not necessarily a new scope and it's also not an isolate scope

Comment: @Phil, but _isolate_scope_ directive applied only to form that adding item, if you see on delete - not. i try remove it and add - nothing changes.

Comment: Without digging in to the `ngRepeat` and `ngForm` code, I'd only be guessing. If it can be reproduced in a simple example, I'd submit it as a bug

Comment: I can't reproduce it simply so my guess would be something in Ionic is messing with it ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/8EG6PW5LDOptghK8Yrxy?p=preview

Comment: @Phil, seems this problem in `ionic` with nested `ng-form`,`ng-model` and `required`: http://plnkr.co/edit/7edJiUiMO7DydRCK4ref?p=preview this a minimal sample i think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93036/discussion-between-grundy-and-phil).

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same problem; “Splice not working”. In my case, I had to resolve as below just in case if it helps someone.

If you are dealing with objects, please note 'indexOf' works for array not for Object inside the array. You can do something like below to identify the index and handle this case;

```
$scope.removeReport = function(report) {
    var index = $scope.contact.reports.map(function(r) { return r.id;}).indexOf(report.id);
        if (index >= 0) {
          $scope.contact.reports.splice(index, 1);
        }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use Index in place of Item

```
<button type="button" class="button button-assertive button-clear icon ion-close-circled" ng-click="deleteItem($index)"></button>
```

Also in Controller

```
$scope.deleteItem = function(index) {
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Comment: if you try it, you can see that this not work in this case

Comment: This Will Work 100% sure

Comment: are you try it in OP sample? :-)